# php time out functionality with some special function

Tags: php

Hello I'm writing a simple php code with database.

I'm just curious to write a additional feature  that

"log out if a certain time period without any action behaved"

for example I log on with some ID. and it will activate next php file.

and if i don't submit anything or click anything for a while. it gives you a warning

sign and log out automatically. Is this hard to write? or can do with simple time function?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this question:

[PHP auto-logout after 10 mins of inactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289539/php-auto-logout-after-10-mins-of-inactivity)

Basically, there's no way to do it without JavaScript(this solution uses [JQuery IdleTimeout plugin](https://github.com/philpalmieri/jquery-idleTimeout)) that, after 10 minutes, shows a popup saying that the user is inactive and redirects to a certain page, where you can implement your php script logging the user out.

Create a php file that activates this plugin and include it in all of your pages that need to be watched for inactivity.